# excel formula match cells background color

Tags: excel, vba

I'm after some help with this code I found on this site that I'm using but it doesn't quite do what I need.

[Code found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583313/excel-vba-match-font-color-and-cell-background-color)

I have 2 sheets "Production" and "Components". "Production" is a list of data which includes a column(B) of job numbers. "Components" is a sheet of columns based on varies locations, in the cells below are job numbers.

I need code that matches the cell background color of the numbers on "Components" to the cell background color of the same value on "Production" sheet.

The code below does this but with 2 problems.

First, it searches the entire column(B) in "Production" which can often have the same number repeated. I only need it to search until it finds the first instance it finds from the top of the sheet.

Second, when the macro runs it takes ages to check through all the numbers, I need something quicker if possible?

```
Sub Worksheet_Update()
  Dim wsHighlight As Worksheet
  Dim wsData As Worksheet
  Dim rngColor As Range
  Dim rngFound As Range
  Dim KeywordCell As Range
  Dim strFirst As String

  Set wsHighlight = Sheets("Production")
  Set wsData = Sheets("Components")

  With wsData.Columns("A:M")
    For Each KeywordCell In wsHighlight.Range("B3", wsHighlight.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Cells
      Set rngFound = .Find(KeywordCell.Text, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
      If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        strFirst = rngFound.Address
        Set rngColor = rngFound
        Do
          Set rngColor = Union(rngColor, rngFound)
          Set rngFound = .Find(KeywordCell.Text, rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
        Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
        rngColor.Interior.Color = KeywordCell.Interior.Color
      End If
    Next KeywordCell
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add the URL where you found this piece of code?

Comment: Link added to OP

Comment: OK, I believe you want to match a job number with a certain fill color from column B of the Production worksheet to the same job number with the same fill color in columns A:M of the Components worksheet. You only require the first match. What do you want to do with the matching jobno/fill color cell in the Components worksheet once you've found it?

Comment: Hi Jeeped, when i  run the macro all I need is to have the cells with job numbers entered on Components sheet to match the background color of the matching cell number in Production.

Comment: On the Production worksheet I have the details of the work we have coming in and out of the workshop. The rows are colored to show what stage of production they are currently at. On the Component worksheet I list the job numbers I have received parts for before putting them on the shelf. I need to be able to see at what stage of production the jobs are at from the component worksheet so I can ensure we don't forget them during manufacturing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a flaw in the original code. The .Find in the Do While should be a FindNext.

```
...
Do
    Set rngColor = Union(rngColor, rngFound)
    Set rngFound = .FindNext(after:=rngFound)  '<~~ here
Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
...
```

Rewrite:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_Update()

    Dim rngColor As Range, rngFound As Range
    Dim KeywordCell As Range, HighlightRange As Range
    Dim strFirst As String, i as long, arr as variant

    redim arr(i)

    With Worksheets("Production")
        Set HighlightRange = .Range(.Cells(3, "B"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
    End With

    With Worksheets("Components").Columns("A:M")
        For Each KeywordCell In HighlightRange
            if iserror(application.match(KeywordCell.Text, arr, 0)) then
                Set rngFound = .Find(KeywordCell.Text, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
                If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
                    strFirst = rngFound.Address
                    Set rngColor = rngFound
                    Do
                        Set rngColor = Union(rngColor, rngFound)
                        Set rngFound = .FindNext(after:=rngFound)
                    Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
                    rngColor.Interior.Color = KeywordCell.Interior.Color
                End If
                redim preserve arr(i)
                arr(i) = KeywordCell.Text
                i=i+1
            end if
        Next KeywordCell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Really appreciate you helping me. I've tried running this and it gives me the result in that it searches all instances and shows the last instance and not the first.

Comment: I've added some redundancy control.

Comment: You sir have nailed it. I ain't going to lie I spent 2 weeks trying to get this to work with my limited knowledge, thank you :)